# Executing javascript present in the value field of inputs - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in html:

```
<form name="foo" action="http://localhost:3000/my_url" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="username" value="alert('hello')" >
</form>
```

I need to get that `JavaScript` in the `value` field for the `input` to execute, but only through the form's `submit`. The reason is that page is a template so I don't control it (can't have

```
<script>
   var input = document.getElementsByName("username");
</script>
```

or any other `<script>`tag added to the page. I'm trying to prove that's possible an attack to take place over malformed `<input>` fields, specially using templates.
How can I have that `Javascript` to execute on the form submission? Remember I'm not allowed to modify the page content except for that piece.
Since I'm doing a `POST` that form, I can set the `<input>` field (and only the `<input>` field) to whatever I want.
I could do

```
username=<script>alert('hello')<script>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<script>alert('hello')<script>" >
```

or

```
username=window.onload = function() { alert('hello') }
<input type="text" name="username" value="window.onload = function() { alert('hello') }" >
```

I have thought about doing a

```
username=document.forms['myform'].onsubmit() = function() { alert('hello') }
<input type="text" name="username" value="document.forms['myform'].onsubmit() = function() { alert('hello') }" >
```

All of those are valid. However I need to get the `Javascript` in the tag to execute. How can I do that? The security flaw is how the` tag can be exploited if not properly sanitized. As per @guest271314 "requirement include adding  tag ..."

Comment: `eval()` will achieve what you need. Are you using this as an example of why you shouldn't allow unsanitised JS code to be placed in HTML inputs? I hope so, because otherwise this is terrible - and is a massive security flaw.

Comment: _"I'm not allowed to modify the page content except for that piece."_ Do you mean you _can_ change some code in the area of the submit event, or that you can only modify the actual value in the `<input>`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that's exactly what I want ... could you formulate it in an answer?

Comment: @JamesThorpe In the actual problem I have a `Javascript` code that will modify the `<form>` in order to capture the value in the `username` input... I can edit the question with that piece of `Javascript` if you want

Comment: @JamesThorpe I only can modify the actual value in the `<input>`

Comment: @philippe If cannot add `js` to page , how can add `document.forms['myform'].onsubmit() = function() { alert('hello') }` ? Can change `html` of page ?

Comment: Regarding your edits - can you imagine the chaos and security implications if browsers executed code contained in a value attribute?  Do you not think that people would have spotted this before?  Browsers really aren't going to execute arbitrary code given to them as a form value.

Comment: @JamesThorpe still, there must be a way to exploit that flaw and that's what I'm trying to prove ...

Comment: What flaw?  There is no flaw.  The value of an input field is just text.  Until you put something in the page somewhere else that reads the text, interprets it as script and executes it, it will just sit there, as text.

Comment: If you are rendering html using a template engine of an unsanitized and unencoded user input you can actually execute the code by posting to the server "><script>alert('foo')</script>". The first ">" closes the input and your script tag is rendered next

Comment: @devconcept you arrived at the point!! Could you elaborate an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a template engine to render html content the server normally sanitize and escape it to prevent passive injection of cross site scripts or XSS for short.

Such attack can be easily achieved on a server that does not enforce the previously mentioned security measures by posting malformed content that will happily be rendered later by the template engine.

For example a form that sends user input

```
<form name="foo" action="http://localhost:3000/my_url" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="username" value="" >
</form>
```

If the user sends something like `"><script>alert('foo')</script>` and later you display this input in another form

```
<form name="bar" action="http://localhost:3000/my_other_url" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="@template_engine_render(posted_username_value)@" >
</form>
```

The resulting output will be

```
<form name="bar" action="http://localhost:3000/my_other_url" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="">
    <script>alert('foo')</script>
</form>
```

Because the "> caracters close the input tag and you will end up executing arbitrary user javascript code in your page.

This is why "Never trust user input" is one of the most basic security rules of the web.

Comment: Done, Thanks for the help! That's what I was looking for. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I didn't know at fully what was going on, and Iearnt in the process. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `Function`

Note, submission of `form` at stacksnippets appear blocked; substituted `click` event for `submit` event; i.e.g., `click` on `input` at stacksnippets for value of `input` to be called as parameter to `Function`.

```js
document.forms["foo"].onclick = function(e) {
  Function(this.children[0].value)()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="foo" action="" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="username" value="alert('hello')" >
</form>
```

Comment: Would you add the `document.forms["foo"].onclick = function(e) {
  Function(this.children[0].value)()
}` to the value field?

Comment: Have come to realize that no external script can be used... only whatever gets entered into input as value. Question was a bit misleading

Comment: @philippe Not certain ? Try ? Though both stacksnippets and jsfiddle appear to utilize `iframe` elements to display `html` ; perhaps try at local `html` page ? Difficult to interpret what actual requirement is ? See `Function` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function _"Names to be used by the function as formal argument names. Each must be a string that corresponds to a valid JavaScript identifier or a list of such strings"_ , _"Function objects created with the Function constructor are parsed when the function is created."_

Comment: @charlietfl Still attempting to grasp what actual expected result is ? Execute arbitrary `js` input into `form` `input` field ?

Comment: @guest271314 That's exactly it

Comment: but after it is submitted and inserted in another page or form, and can only come from user input in the field

Comment: @philippe `value` of `input` filed is text `String` ; without converting `String` to `Function` , should not execute ?

Comment: @guest271314 devconcept gave the actual clue about that ... " 
If you are rendering html using a template engine of an unsanitized and unencoded user input you can actually execute the code by posting to the server "><script>alert('foo')</script>". The first ">" closes the input and your script tag is rendered next "

Comment: @charlietfl _"but after it is submitted and inserted in anothe rpage or form"_ ? _"after"_ ? Could define function as variable , which should retain it as `String` , then call `Function` at another page; e.g., `var x = Function('alert(1)');` `x` is now `function anonymous() {
alert(1)
}` ; at other page , call `x()` - though the `alert` portion must be defined at "other" page. `alert` is global, should be called ; if not global , define as global _before_ calling - within same string argument ?

Comment: well now you are using script tags phillipe... there's no rocket science there...that is certainly a known security risk and why people sanitize tags. If that is what this whole question is about it's a big waste of time

Comment: @philippe See, at OP _"can't have"_ _"`<script>` tag"_ ? Does requirement permit including `script` tag, or excluding `script` tag from `js` , attempts to execute arbitrary `js` from `input type=text` `value` ?

Comment: @charlietfl The question is how to exploit unsanitized  `<script>` tags to execute. I know about the security risks involved on that, however the question is how can I take advantage of that as an exploit ... that's why I'm asking the question make sense?

Comment: @philippe Appear contrary to description at OP regarding `script` tag inclusion , exclusion: _"See, at OP "can't have" "`<script>` tag" ?"_ ? Perhaps add , edit original Question to include _"requirement include adding <script> tag ..."_ ?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm sorry for the confusion ... I'm learning in the process as well ... will edit the question

Comment: I'm really about over this question. Original specification should have been a lot more clear since it said no tags. You can find all of this by searching the web

Comment: @charlietfl Yes. Perhaps several ways to accomplish expected result. Excluding `script` tags from solution was challenging portion; comments appeared initially to insist on no script tag approach ? Should be few options available to test now; `eval` , your solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/30171161/2801559, `Function` - and `script` tags.

Comment: @guest271314 right an probably lots of white papers on what ugly script in a tag can do...all easily found in a google search